# How can I link locally downloaded bootstrap into react?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I can't seem to find a way on how to use bootstrap locally in react without npm or yarn bootstrap installation or even without CDN, every tutorial I find on how to use bootstrap they don't explain using bootstrap locally.
Please I need steps on how I can achieve this thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know this for sure, so please correct me if I am wrong. I am just trying to help you to the best of my knowledge.

There are multiple ways.
The first way is to import the CSS in the app.js (or the start of the React app). For the CSS you should have a file called `bootstrap.css` that contains all the CSS for Bootstrap. `import './bootstrap.css'`.

The second way is to import it in the html file. If you add the the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">`.

**I don't know if this is the way it should be done!**

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I added the bootstrap.min.css in my react SRC folder and then imported it into my index.jsx file